# jquery button onclick input validation (not on form submit)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form with action="autosave.php". This saves as normal when enter is clicked or the submit button is pressed.

```
<input type="submit" id="save" value="Save Changes" />
```

I am also using jquery autosave, which automatically submits the form every 10 secs

```
$('form.checklist').autosave({interval:10000,......});
```

My problem is, i want to put jquery validation on the form, but i dont want it to validate for any any the above 3 processes.

I only want the validation to take place when a button is clicked.

```
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="location.href='submit.php'" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button id="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"  type="button">Submit</button>
<script>
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        dovalidation (obviously this must be your validation function)
        if(validation==true){
            location.href='submit.php';
        }else{
            e.preventDefault; return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: :brilliant thank you. I have used your code and put in my validation function, but now when i click submit, it does not do anything. I am using errorLabelContainer: $("#RegisterErrors") in my validation function, with <div id="RegisterErrors" style="display:none"></div>, but the errors dont appear. Do i need to add something in the else statement?

Comment: I assume you don't have a validation function built?

Comment: Yes validation is built in, works great on the form  when i submit and the errorLabelContainer also works. but does not work with the above method. I think the else statement is being called but then not displaying the errors.

Comment: Ok, remove the return false; statement

Comment: did that and nothing again, i also checked the 3 checkboxes i have the validation on and it didn't submit the form either. So i think its the if... else... statements that are not being called